# Why is Visual Studios using pip version 21.2.4 when i have version 22.0.4?

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

Im trying to install gravity ai (`pip install gravity ai`) but I keep running into this error

```
 × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]


To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\User 1\OneDrive\Desktop\Gravity_AI_Upload\env1\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common for IDEs to use their own copy of `pip`.

However, if you create a virtual environment, you can upgrade pip in that with

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Using that version could then solve your problem. However, it seems more likely that you should try installing this package on a previous version of Python. `gravityai` doesn't install for me on 3.10, but works OK on 3.6.

On Python 3.9, it does install, but it has conflicting requirements. It includes `gravityai 0.1.3.post1` which requires `websockets` to be version 9.1, but it also includes `pyppeteer 0.2.5`, which only supports `websockets` versions 8.1 or over, but not 9.0 or over. That's a conflict `pip` cannot resolve and should be taken up with the developers.

I'm guessing uninstalling `websockets` and going with either 8.1 or 9.1 might work, but you may lose some specific functionality. It's possible that you can figure out some other changes to the dependency tree that resolve these conflicts, by going back to older versions of libraries that have `pyppeteer` as a dependency - but that's a rabbit hole. If you do want to go that route, try this:

```
pip install pipdeptree
pipdeptree
```

To see what is requiring what exactly, to then know what to try and downgrade.

If you don't mind using an older version of Python, those dependency issues go away, but of course you're no longer using the latest version of everything - so you may miss some functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and info.  I was also thinking the issue might be with the version of python I'm using.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: Well, to be perfectly clear, the issue is really with the maintainers of the package you're trying to use. They appear to be doing a fairly poor job of ensuring their deployment works, probably by not being clear or strict enough about what the exact requirements and dependencies are on each version of Python. However, I hope you find a mix that happens to work, and that they improve this in future releases.